# BibTex to EndNote

Tags: bibtex, msword

I have gone through a lot of seemingly similar questions/issue but have not find a solution.

Since we are working as a group there are some that prefer to write using MS Word-EndNote. I have all references in BibTeX and these are updated from time to time (when something moves from pre-print to actual publication with addition of issue/page etc, minor corrections in citations in the main database, etc). I have no problem importing my automatically generated BibTeX file into EndNote. However, this BibTeX file gets updated from time to time and I would like to keep the EndNote database up to date as well. Re-importing the new BibTeX file into EndNote makes the process unnecessarily difficult, since you would end up doing deduplication of the results. Does anyone have a solution? There is a willingness to change to Zotero, so if you have a solution using Zotero, I'm also quite interested.

Simply put: `.bib` file that is updated from time to time, is there a way to keep my EndNote/Zotero database updated based on this `.bib` file?

Comment: From my experience there is no simple solution for this problem. I use mendeley, when I need to use my bibtex citation in MS Word (or similar). The import worked better than with Endnote. Instead of importing the whole database each time (what you do not want to do): What about importing only a diff?

Comment: Dear @daniel.neumann, Thank you for your thoughts. I discovered mendeley actually offers API access, this might offer possibilities. I did also contact Endnote support to see if they can come up with something...

Comment: In my search for BibTex - endnote communication I came across: https://github.com/hash-bang/RefLib ; it seems like a decent way of exporting references to endnote xml format.

Comment: You can use [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) to convert BibTeX to EndNote. See https://help.jabref.org/en/EndNoteFilters. [JabRef's FAQ](http://help.jabref.org/en/FAQwindows) also lists other options how to directly interact with BibTeX in word.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this: I don't think this is too broad, by any standard. The question is quite clear and specific, and potential answers would not be too broad either.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to edit *both* the BibTeX file and reference manager database, I would suggest using the reference manager for editing entries and automatically exporting to BibTeX (also see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/1755) for a discussion of the problem). A working combination is [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) plus [BetterBibTeX](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/).